# How to check if specific string exists in columns of different tables? (Microsoft SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 6 different tables, say: dbo.One, dbo.Two, dbo.Three,.....,dbo.Six

I want to check if a certain string (ex: "CatWS_Energy_CB") exists in ANY of the columns of the 6 different tables (This string is not the whole column name but is contained in the column name).  Is there a way to do this?  I'm trying to do an if statement in SQL but I'm not quite sure how to approach this first part.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Is this a one off task? If not you might want to look into Full Text Indexing.

Comment: @MartinSmith  Thanks, I'll look into that...haven't done that yet in SQL but am willing to learn!

Comment: Actually I've just read the question again and am a bit confused. Are you looking for column **names** containing that string or column values?

Comment: @MartinSmith  I'm looking for the column names which makes this a bit more difficult.

Comment: So you mean something like `SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) FROM sys.columns WHERE name LIKE '%CatWS_Energy_CB%' AND object_id IN (object_id('One'),object_id('Two'))`?

Comment: @MartinSmith  Your code seems to be what I'm looking for.  I will give it a try and let you know if it works.

Comment: @MartinSmith  Would this work if the tables are in a different database?  Say my database name is `AnalyticsV2` and the tables are in database `Catastrophe`

Comment: It could be altered to work in that context, yes, if it is doing what you actually need in the first place.

Comment: It looks like it's doing what I need it to do I just need to change it so it looks at the other database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on discussion in the comments I think this is what you need.

```
SELECT Object_name(object_id, Db_id('Catastrophe'))
FROM   Catastrophe.sys.columns
WHERE  name LIKE '%CatWS_Energy_CB%'
       AND object_id IN ( Object_id('Catastrophe.dbo.One'), 
                          Object_id('Catastrophe.dbo.Two'), 
                          Object_id('Catastrophe.dbo.Three') )
```

Comment: I do have one question.  If I use `'%CatWS_Energy_US x GOM%'` in my like statement, I get a result which tells me that `CatWS_Energy_US` exists.  Is this because `'%CatWS_Energy_US x GOM%'` contains `CatWS_Energy_US`?  If so, is there a way to change this?

Comment: The result returned is the table name not the column name. To add the column name add `name` to the select list.

Comment: Makes sense...I just want it to return the table if the full text is contained in the column of that table because just `'CatWS_Energy_US'` is not contained in that table but it's saying it is.